# Problems inheriting operator*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, operators

I've been having some troubles trying to inherit operators in C++, using VS2013. I have a class A which implements several methods and a class B which inherits from A. Class A also implements an operator * which interacts with another class C, something like:

```
class A
{
    ...
    C operator*(const C &_objectC) {...}
}

class B: public A
{
    ...
}
```

Since the changes between A and B don't change the implementation of the operator *, would be nice to inherit it from A instead of re-implement it. I've been trying to do that, but the compiler can't find the operator implemented by A.

In the following code:

```
B foo = ...;
C bar = ...;
C result = foo * bar;
```

I'm having this error:

```
error C2679: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class C' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I know that operator= has to be overloaded because compiler always generates a version of it for each class, so you can't inherit it directly.

¿Can other operators be inherited? My understanding was it is possible, but my compiler doesn't agree. ¿Is there something I'm doing wrong or I just have to re-implement the operator only to call the parent class's operator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm able to compile this fine in VS 2013.

(Note: I'm assuming the operator* is public, and that part was just left out for brevity.)

Comment: Can you post an actual example that doesn't compile?  This works fine on g++.

Answer (score 2):

The following code, equivalent to what you have presented (at the time of writing this answer), only with semicolons added and a `main` function filled out, works:

```
class C {};

class A
{
public:
    auto operator*( C const &_objectC ) const
        -> C
    { return C(); }
};

class B: public A
{
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    B foo = B();
    C bar = C();
    C result = foo * bar;
}
```

Hence you have not provided the code where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the operator as a non-member function and the compiler should compile the code.For example

```
C operator *( const A &, const C & );
```

Or you could declare this operator as virtual and redefine it in the derived class.

Also can it be that the operator is declared as private in class A?

Comment: Re "can it be that the operator is declared as private in class A?", if it were private then the compiler should complain about inaccessible, not about not found.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf I agree. But the code snippet that presented as usual is not even compiled.:) It seems it is very difficult to write a simple code that reproduces the problem.:)